# Mounting NFS share

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs

I have got a server with failed hard drive. I would like to retrieve the data that I have on the disk. For that I created an ubuntu live cd and I am using it in one of the clients. I am trying to mount the linux share from the server in my ubuntu livecd.

I am using this command to mount the sda1 share:

mount -t cifs //(ip address of server)/dev/sda1 /mnt/cifs

but I always keep on getting the error "Unable to find suitable address."

I am also sure that I do have the sda1 partition in my server. Could anyone please suggest what might be the cause for this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't share partitions, you can only share filesystems. You can't share special files such as device nodes.

You could try to retrieve the data on the server using dd and netcat, but likelihood is that reading the disk image will fail at the kernel level when you hit the bad blocks.

Run "badblocks" on the server first to mark the bad blocks as such, then try to recover the disk image using `dd if=/dev/sda |netcat reveiver_host receiver_port`